# How to save a moviepy VideoClip to a file

Tags: python, pickle, dump, moviepy

So I am trying to pickle.dump() a dictionary in python. Here is the general structure of my dictionary:

```
{"key": [tkinter.Button, moviepy.VideoFileClip, int]}
```

etc.
Now I am not able to run the pickle.dump() on the `moviepy.VideoFileClip` object - it comes up with this error:

```
cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

does anyone know how I can save a dictionary with a moviepy videofileclip to a file (I might try numpy arrays soon)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pickle a MoviePy `VideoFileClip` because it doesn't store all the video data inside it, it lazily loads the video data from an FFmpeg process when it is requested.

You'll have to convert the `VideoFileClip` to a numpy array with `np.array(clip.iter_frames())`, which converts the returned generator into a numpy array.

Comment: Ok! Does this also include the audio or will I also have to do VideoFileClip.audio.to_soundarray()?

Comment: This is only the video, you will have to handle audio and/or mask separately, yes.

Comment: When I try the `np.array(clip.iter_frames())` instead of going through the generator it just stores the object?

Comment: Oh ok, you can just do `list(clip.iter_frames())` or `np.array(list(clip.iter_frames()))` then?

Comment: Ok - only slight issue is that this takes a long time (lots longer than audio.to_soundarray()) - is there any way to speed this up? It lags out my computer a lot

Comment: Well yes, you’re loading the entire video into memory, which is a bad idea. Apparently I forgot to mention that bit in my answer. You shouldn’t really be doing this at all. Just keep the video file and read it in via another VideoFileClip when you need it.

Comment: But I am making a video editor and afiak the one I tested out auto saved the video file? is there some way I can save it with the lazy ffmpeg saving you mentioned?

Comment: Just save a reference to the file name and create a new VideoFileClip when you need it (presumably on project load?). If you want to ensure that the video is not deleted then you could copy the file into somewhere that your program controls and then use that copy instead. Idk if video editors do this, I suspect they they don’t, and that they just rely on video files still being in their original location.

Comment: Yes I think they rely on them being in the same place. Problem is the users can cut/trim the clips (so they aren't the same as the original video file)

Comment: Oh right, I see the issue. You'd have similar issues if you just saved `clip.iter_frames` though, as not everything is baked into the frames (such as fps). I guess you need to write an alternative to `VideoFileClip` that does that allows you to close the reader before pickling and reopen it when you unpickle.

Comment: Sounds very complicated - I think I'll just make it easy to do stuff fast so people won't have to save it